# convergence action on the boundary of hyperbolic groups

Tags: geometric-group-theory

Let G be a word-hyperbolic group acting on its boundary, which is homeomorphic to $S^n$ (n-sphere), effectively. Does this imply that G acts on the boundary as a convergence group of $S^n$?

If this is true in general, is it easy to see, at least for n = 1 or 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bowditch proved much more.  Namely, if a group $\Gamma$ acts properly discontinuously on a $\delta$-hyperbolic space $X$, then $\Gamma$ acts as a convergence group on $\partial X$.  See Lemma 1.11 of his paper

B.H. Bowditch,
Convergence groups and configuration spaces,
in ``Geometric Group Theory Down Under, proceedings of a Special Year in Geometric Group Theory, Canberra, Australia'' (ed. J.Cossey, C.F.Miller III, W.D.Neumann, M.Shapiro), de Gruyter (1999), 23-54.

which is available [here](http://www.warwick.ac.uk/~masgak/papers/bhb-convergence.dvi.gz).  To get the result you want, consider the action of $\Gamma$ on its Cayley graph.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a theorem of [Brian Bowditch.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Bowditch)

Comment: I think it was first written by P.Tukia in "Convergence groups and Gromov's metric hyperbolic spaces", New Zealand J. Math. 23 (1994), no. 2, 157–187. 

Comment: I guess Brian's result is really the converse...